# Choose file with Input - Python?

Tags: python

I am playing first time with input in python and getting some error on this code:

```
    import random

    x = input("Name of the File? ")
    lines = open(x).read().splitlines()
    myline =random.choice(lines)
    print(myline)
```

when I run it, it ask me for name.. then I enter: data.txt
and getting this error:

```
    NameError: name 'data' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead:

```
import random

x = raw_input("Name of the File? ")
lines = open(x).read().splitlines()
myline =random.choice(lines)
print(myline)
```

The reason that `input()` isn't working for you is that it reads your input and then attempts to evaluate it with `eval`. When you enter the input `data` it attempts to `eval(data)` which results in `NameError` (unless there happens to be a variable with that name in scope). You can make it work with `input()`, however, you need to enter quotes so that it is evaluated as a string, e.g. enter `"data"`.

Comment: @Jerome - glad to hear it.

Comment: @Jerome If this answer worked for you, you should click the outlined checkmark below the votes to "accept" it. See [What does it mean when an answer is accepted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you have any questions.